# Quadratic Form but with different vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, terminology, quadratic-forms

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ we say the expression below is a **quadratic form**
$$
x^\top Ax \in\mathbb{R}
$$
Given another vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is there a name for the following operation?
$$
x^\top A y
$$

Comment: The mapping $(x, y)\mapsto x^{tr}Ay$ is called a bilinear form.

Comment: Technically, that isn’t a quadratic form. A quadratic form is the map $x\mapsto x^{\top}Ax.$ Or, even more classically, it is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$ in $k[x_1, x_2,\dots ,x_n].$ But the value at a particular $x\in k^n$ is not a quadratic form.